# Dynamic chanching images in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want to change image in kv file every time when I click button. The problem is i have one image which is changing every time when you clik on the button, but the image stays the same

```
class RandomWindow(Screen,Widget):
    img_src = StringProperty('Alcohol-Abuse.jpg')

    def randomDrink(self):
        ...

        r = requests.get(photo,stream=True, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

        img_src = StringProperty('img.jpg')

        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open("img.jpg", 'wb') as f:
                r.raw.decode_content = True
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

------ kv.file---

```
Label:
    pos_hint:{"x":0.05, "y":0.35}
    size_hint: 0.45,0.5
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: root.img_src
```

Comment: In your method you create a new StringProperty, but that doesn't do anything useful. Perhaps you meant to update the existing one: `self.img_src = 'img.jpg'`

Comment: hmm didn't work the problem is that I don't know how to "reload" this canvas with the image. Every time I click the new picture is replacing the image but the picture in canvas stays the same :/

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.reload

Comment: thxxx it worked! I'm very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
class RandomWindow(Screen,Widget):

def randomDrink(self):
....
    r = requests.get(photo,stream=True, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open("img.jpg", 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)

    self.ids.im.reload()
```

---kv.file----

```
Image:
    id: im
    source:'img.jpg'
```